# SMS Gateways

Tags: c#

My application needs to send notification to users by SMS.
Is there any free International SMS gateways which can be used by .NET application?

Comment: "Free" SMS? As in "not paying for sms" ? I'm curious if such a service exists...

Comment: I guess you can see the Earlier Post

[See SMS GateWay][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464474/sms-application/10320513

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [Ozeki NG](http://www.ozekisms.com/)

Here's a complete C# tutorial about it: 
http://www.ozekisms.com/c-sharp-sms-api/index_p_php_q_ow_page_number_e_315opt.html