# SMS application

Tags: c#, sms

I wish to develop a sms application in C#.net.

So please help me by guiding me how to create such an application from scratch.

Comment: are you trying to create a SMS gateway?

Comment: I asked a similar question at: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/533/how-to-add-sms-text-messaging-functionality-to-my-website

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best thing to do would be get an account on a cheap SMS/Voice provider. I use [Twilio](http://twilio.com) for a ton of spare time stuff. Their service works *great*, and it's really cheap ($1 a month for a unique phone number, and $0.03 per SMS message). Another service is [Tropo](http://tropo.com). They charge more per month for a phone number, but less for each message.

Twilio also provides [an open source C# API wrapper](http://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp/).

Comment: 3 cent per send adds up. there's a way to use google  voice to send SMS for free btw

Comment: @ina, sure--you can use Google Voice if you want, but they don't have an API and don't permit commercial use. As soon as you're sending enough that you'd begin to feel the 3 cents per message, you'll be on their radar and might get blocked.

Answer (score 1):

I was using ActiveExprerts SMS and MMS Toolkit, they have a good example on how you develop stuff from it and it supports a lot of GSM Modems, Mobile Phone and SMPP SMSC Providers. If you need further help I have an old project which I implemented but its in VB. Have a try and let me know its in http://www.activexperts.com/xmstoolkit/

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you should go for the free service provider ie. way2sms or 160by2

[Download full Source Code Here](http://getcode.in/2012/04/way2sms-api-for-asp-net-c-sharp/)

for that you can integrate the Api for that in your application.

Here is the Code

http://alfasms.alfredfrancis.in/?uname=YOUR_USERNAME&pass=YOUR_PASSWORD&to=YOUR_RECEPTIANT&mess=YOUR_MESSAGE&gateway=YOUR_GATEWAY

```
>> Where YOUR_USERNAME your way2sms/160by2/fullonsms/sms440/site2sms USERNAME(ie mobile number)
>>Where YOUR_PASSWORD your way2sms/160by2/fullonsms/sms440/site2sms PASSWORD.
>> Where YOUR_RECEPTIANT is to which number you want to send SMS.
>> Where YOUR_MESSAGE is the message you want to send.
>> Where YOUR_GATEWAY is way2sms/160by2/fullonsms/sms440/site2sms.

string connectionString = "<a href="http://alfasms.alfredfrancis.in/?uname=YOUR_USERNAME&pass=YOUR_PASSWORD&to=YOUR_RECEPTIANT&mess=YOUR_MESSAGE&gateway=YOUR_GATEWAY">http://alfasms.alfredfrancis.in/?uname=YOUR_USERNAME&pass=YOUR_PASSWORD&to=YOUR_RECEPTIANT&mess=YOUR_MESSAGE&gateway=YOUR_GATEWAY</a>";



try
 {

System.IO.Stream SourceStream = null;

System.Net.HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(connectionString);

myRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();

SourceStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());

string str = reader.ReadLine();

}

catch (Exception ex)
 {

}
```